# NSDictionary flatten hierarchy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I've got an NSDictionary object like this:

```
dictionary: {
    data =     {
        "access_token" = "xxx";
        "expires_in" = 00;
        "refresh_token" = "yyy";
        "token_type" = bearer;
    };
}
```

How can I flatten it so that I remove the 'data' object? Is there a quick way to do that?
So the output should look like this:

```
dictionary: {

        "access_token" = "xxx";
        "expires_in" = 00;
        "refresh_token" = "yyy";
        "token_type" = bearer;
};
```

Comment: I hope the access token data is not valid by the way.

Comment: What is your key for dictionary and data?

Comment: dont you thing you have wrong format of the dictionary

Comment: `NSDictionary *result = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *dataDict = [mainDict  objectForKey:@"data"];
```

Comment: Doesnt work.... I get
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: this wouldnt result in a flat dictionary

Comment: @Imme22009 then you are not giving exactly what your dictionary is having

Comment: As I said, this wouldnt flatten it. this would result in a dict with a key dictionary which has the value dataDict

Comment: @Daij-Djan is it fine now.. Don't you think he has wrong dict object.. in dictionary you have `key : value` not `key = value`

Answer (score 0):

flat dict in your example:

```
//grab data
NSDictionary *data = [yourDict objectForKey:@"data"];
assert(data != nil);
NSDictionary *flatDict = data; //OR data.copy // OR [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:data];
```

Comment: @InderKumarRathore yes, I know. I wasnt sure if he wanted a copy or not or whatever :D I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like "data" is an NSDictionary. Try

```
id what = [dict objectForKey : @"data"];
NSLog(@"%@", [what class]);
```

What does it say?

Answer (score 0):

using recursive function, the only problem with this method is it will replace the old data if key happened to be the same in the nested dictionary

```
- (NSDictionary *)flattedDictionary{
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
  for (NSString *key in self.allKeys) {
    id object = [self objectForKey:key];
    if (![object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] && !isNull(object)) {
        [dict setObject:object
                 forKey:key];
    } else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
        [dict addEntriesFromDictionary:[object flattedDictionary]];
    }
}
  return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict];
}
```